# Safari (Host App) give selected text to App Extension?

Tags: ios-app-extension

Possible to get a text selection out from safari (host app)to an app extension, or only the URL?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. You can create a JavaScript file as part of your Action Extension. This is described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) since you also have to add a `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` key to your extension's Info.plist.

Inside the JavaScript file you can define a `run` function which allows you to define values to pass to your native extension code. Here you can get the selected text as shown in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) and pass this through to your extension.

Here's a quick example of how this might work on the JavaScript side:

```js
var MyExtensionJavaScriptClass = function() {};

MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.prototype = {
    run: function(arguments) {
        // Pass the selected text through
        arguments.completionFunction({"text": window.getSelection().toString()});
    }
};

// The JavaScript file must contain a global object named "ExtensionPreprocessingJS".
var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new MyExtensionJavaScriptClass;
```

Comment: I just tried creating an action extension with Xcode 6.2b2 and there is no `Action.js` file. What steps do you take that causes Xcode to include that file?

Comment: This is part of the default template in Xcode 6.1.1. You can add these files yourself if you'd prefer. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html) for the Info.plist changes you'll need to make as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not part of the template, when I try it. If I add an action extension, the template created by Xcode does not contain that file. That page also does not indicate that the file is included as part of the template. If you are seeing this happen, please describe what you're doing in more detail, because I can't get Xcode to do it.

Comment: Since it isn't in the template for you just create the js file yourself. Then add the relevant keys to your Info.plist as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: You should update your answer so that it does not claim that this is automatically included.

Comment: Ah yep it looks like this must have been removed in 6.1.1 and it was generated with 6.1.